What sort of impact did the discovery that water could be broken down (via electrolysis) into gas have?
Given that water was at one time considered to be one of the "elements" I would have guessed that this experiment would be more prominent in popular science than it seems to be: When Nicholson in 1800 discovered that bubbles accumulated around the wires leading from a battery immersed in water and concluded that these were actually constituents of the water itself (not what most people would have guessed immediately), this was surely one of the most important events in the history of science.
But unlike Newton and his apple, this event, interestingly coming at the very beginning of the 19th century, does not seem to have made its way into the popular imagination.
I assume that after William Nicholson told others of his experiment it was repeated with water and other substances throughout Europe probably, but I have read nothing of this.
I would like to understand the effect on scientific thought that the discovery had.

This question needs more focus. Try to adapt your question into something verifiable. Do you want to know if the discovery was well cited in the first half of the 19th century? Do you want to know if Nicholson got some sort public recognition? Do you want a timeline of other electrolysis related discoveries?

I'd like to add that it this experiment was significant enough that we even know of it. That by itself is not a small feat in the big scope of things.

First, one should note that the very notion of element was muddled at that point, and was somewhat dependent on the theory of chemical reaction one adopted.
Consider the following facts: by the late 18th century several people had already isolated hydrogen and oxygen, and knew that combining them would result in water. Cavendish noted that the reaction is most efficient when combining two parts of hydrogen (by volume) with one part of oxygen. Yet Cavendish was unsure whether the conclusion from this was that water was not a simple substance. This is because phlogiston was still the most popular account of chemical reaction and so both hydrogen and oxygen were understood in light of this theory.
It probably was Lavoisier's introduction of the concept of conservation of mass in 1783, which led to a shift from phlogiston to caloric, that paved the way to viewing water as a compound. Up to the 18th century combustion (together with distillation) was one of the primary ways of assessing chemical composition. A major fact for early chemists was that metals (particularly metallic scraps) caught fire and the combustion produced an earthy substance (what we call today metallic oxides). This same earthy substance did not catch fire, but upon being roasted in charcoal produced the original metal. So it was thought that flammable substances (such as metals) had in themselves a "fire principle", called phlogiston, that was exhausted on combustion but could be reintroduced by roasting. The major change was in the generation of Cavendish when precise measurements noted that the earthy substance was heavier than the original metal, so combustion could not be understood as something leaving the metal (incidentally, that's why in redox terminology the opposite of oxidation is reduction, when metallic oxides are reduced they literally reduce in mass). By introducing conservation of mass Lavoisier, arguably, gave rise to the notion that in a chemical reaction, the substance with less mass is simpler than the one with more. So if hydrogen and oxygen are lighter than the producing water you can conclude that water is not a simple substance.
Therefore by the time of Nicholson's experiment, whether water was an element or not was at least a 20-year-old discussion that could not simply be settled by experiment but was predicated on theoretical views. One should bear in mind that despite Lavoisier's fame, phlogiston did not fade away immediately. As a matter of fact, in 1782 de Morveau produced a table of simple substances which included oxygen and hydrogen, but not water, yet De Morveau adhered to phlogiston theory (noticeably to deal with the reduction of metallic oxides he posited that phlogiston had negative mass). De Morveau's phlogiston was one of the several phlogiston theories that endured during Lavoisier's time.
Turning to Nicholson (and Carlisle), he rejected phlogiston already before the experiment with electrolysis, so water decomposition to him (and many others) while interesting was hardly a surprise, both from a factual and from a theoretical point-of-view. In fact, many others were managing water electrolysis at the same time, such as Ritter and Cruickshank, the latter in the following years achieving electrolysis of many other compounds. At the time of the experiment, electricity was poorly understood, and Nicholson's (and Carlisle's) impact was that they proposed to use the amount of gas formed in water decomposition as a quantitative indicator of electrical currents. So the immediate effect of the experiment was always understood in terms of what we could learn about electricity, not about chemical elements.
That's not to say that the water electrolysis experiment was irrelevant; far from it, it was one among several experiments in early electrochemistry that indicated some connection between electrical phenomena and chemical reactions. But it took decades to understand that electricity was 1) a reliable way of breaking compounds, which led to 2) electrolysis as a major factor in determining what is an element (i.e. something that resists electrolysis), which led to 3) chemical bonds being tied to electric force. Arguably Nicholson's experiment contributed to 1), Davy's electrolysis of alkalis started 2), but to get to 3) required a good theory of acids and bases plus the development of thermodynamics to understand what underlies a chemical reaction. Eventually, electrolysis replaced combustion as a major way to understand chemical reactions and composition, and Nicholson and Carlisle's experiment was an important development in this direction
As a final remark, there is hardly any ground-breaking experiment, a so-called experimentum crucis, but instead a series of experiments that lead to theoretical confusion until the scientific community manages to get some sort of consensus. Even Lavoisier's experiments did not manage to convince everybody to reject phlogiston. We often simplify the history of science to a handful of big moments and great people(usually great men), but often each theory and experiment forms one complex network of discussion.
Cavendish, Lavoisier and others' roles in isolating hydrogen and oxygen is well known and can be found in Wikipedia and references therein. You can find De Morveau and Lavoisier's tables of simple substances at the website meta-synthesis.com (the site has great content for chemistry learning and a full timeline of elements discovery as well as historical periodic tables). For details concerning phlogiston, theories, and experiments up to the 18th century, I recommend J. R. Partington's A History of Chemistry Vol. 3. For early electrochemistry, including a direct discussion of Nicholson and Carlisle's experiment, I used vol. 4 of Partington's A History of Chemistry. As a side note, the four volumes by Partington, although somewhat hard to get access to, are a great reference for the history of chemistry. Unfortunately, vol. 4 covers only until the end of the 19th century, but it has tons of material, and helps translate primary sources to modern-day terminology. Caveat emptor: volume 1 covers everything in ancient and medieval times and I do not guarantee it is accurate. Volume 2 is early modern and, while generally good, contains some errors and simplifications. The last two volumes are good; the last one probably has no competitors for scope and details.

It would be very useful if you would supplement your answer with some source documents that would support the interesting points that you make.

I had not known that the combining of H and O to get water had happened experimentally. Did Nicholson know he was liberating these two gases and conclude this was the inverse process? Certainly combining gas to yield water was impactful, more so than electrolysis perhaps simply because it had preceded it.

@releseabe, Nicholson and Carlisle report two experiments. The first one released only hydrogen, but they noted that the metallic contacts were tarnished and they interpreted it as oxidation. A second, more powerful, experiment released two gases which they weighted and commented that the 2:1 proportion was in accordance with the reported composition of water. I'm unsure whether one could use the terminology of inverse process since Berthollet had not yet coined the notion of reverse reaction, but they clearly noted that their results were aligned with previous experiments.

@releseabe, I edited to include references, sorry for not doing it earlier. Regarding water composition, you could check Henry Cavendish's Wikipedia entry. He decomposed water into H and O and then combining them to form water. Yet he was unsure whether H and O were the elements that formed water or if the reaction merely extracted water from air. It's important to note that at the time it was not clear what "air" was also, and part of the discussions was isolating pure gases like H, N and O and understanding CO2 as a compound. That's because he did not know of atomic theory

Cavendish was a great and subtle guy. But Imagine if Sir Isaac had had a battery!

Yes but isn't half the point that 'Lavoisier's introduction of the concept of conservation of mass in 1783, which led to a shift from phlogiston to caloric, that paved the way to viewing water as a compound' is as difficult for the average high-schooler to grasp as Newton's falling apple is easy?

@RobbieGoodwin I've added a paragraph to try to explain why conservation of mass leads to the abandonment of phlogiston, as the original answer just stated it did without justification, thanks for raising the point. I hope it helps anyone trying to teach this.

Thanks and how can I message you privately, please?

@RobbieGoodwin If you want to discuss this further I'll be happy, you can find me on Discord as cesarulianov
